# MSCOMM32.ocx usage causes Not Trusted Error

Tags: vba, excel, mscomm32

I was using an Excel macro which uses mscomm32.ocx for communicating with the serial port. It was working fine until some one or two month back. Now when we try to run it again it is not working. When I try to load it, it says the "Subject is not trusted for the specified Action".
Can any one help me out!?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually some security upgrades from Microsoft had prevented the older mscomm32.dll from loading. A newer version of the DLL solves the problem Newer version is available as a patch from Microsoft website. But it required VB6 to be installed to work. Do not know how to circumvent that. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely the cause of an update of your Excel installation. Newer Office versions have more strict security policies.

This [document](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/ork2003/HA011403201033.aspx) describes how they can be edited. (Esp. the ActiveX section)

Comment: I was not able to find HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\VBA\Security in my registry.

Comment: Try to create it. If it doesn't exist, the default value will be used.

Comment: Did you try the other policy settings? ActiveX intialization, script security, ...?