# MS Comm Control in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, vb6, serial-port

I am using VBA for Excel. My requirement is that the forms created in VBA shall communicate with external system over serial port of my system. For the same purpose, like we do in VB, I am tring to add MS Comm Control in VBA.

I am able to add MS Comm Control to control panel by selecting the same from `Tools -> Additional Controls`. However, when I try to place `MSComm` control on my form, it gives me following error.

> The subject is not trusted for specified action.

Due to this, I am not able to place the control on my form and hence not able to use the same.

The same behaviour is observed for MS `Winsock` Control.

Found a similar question on stackoverflow: [MSCOMM32.ocx usage causes Not Trusted Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403647/mscomm32-ocx-excel-vba-problem) without any concrete answer.

My installations are: 
Win XP - SP3, MS Office 2010, VB6, MS VS 2010.

Comment: See if this help? http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?622730-MSCOMM-error-in-Excel-2007

Comment: This has solved the issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You've got an old version that has the killbit set: http://msmvps.com/blogs/access/archive/2009/06/14/an-older-version-of-mscomm32-ocx-has-had-the-quot-kill-bit-quot-flag-set.aspx

Comment: @HansPassant Looks like I will have to try the solution that is suggested in this URL. Did not know that the flag is known as killbit flag and there are alternatives available. Will surely try this solution. Have you used it in past?

Answer (score 0):

Legal use of VB6 controls in an Excel macro (or in any 3rd party program or programming language) is restricted.  The only exceptions are when you have licensed Office Developer Edition (or in newer versions of Office the extra developer package that contains VSTO or equivalent) or if you are just creating them for use on the same machine that has VB6 installed.

But your problem is probably either related to Microsoft kill-bitting the OCX (which prevents use in IE, and maybe in Office?), or more likely that you are using 64-bit Excel (and thus 64-bit VBA).

Comment: My system is a 32-bit machine.

Comment: "Killbit is a security feature in web browsers based on Microsoft's Trident engine (such as Internet Explorer) and other ActiveX containers that respect the killbit (such as *Microsoft Office*)." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killbit

Answer (score 0):

I got similar problem but with MsWinSck.OCX. I fixed it by loading ActiveX Compatibility Manager from http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/acm.html and enable the OCX (Winsck.OCX) by selecting the OCX in  the lines then click the green LED on the menu.

Hope this may help.